# Convertendo arquivo word para pdf

Tags: c#, microsoft-word

Existe uma biblioteca free que eu posso converter arquivo word para pdf ?

Tenho arquivo word salvo database com tipo `varbinary(MAX)` e recupero como `byte[]` em C# e quero converter word para pdf para mostrar na página HTML.

Eu mostro na página HTML utilizando [ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/), porem ela aceita somente **PDF** e **ODT**.

Aqui está o código de retorno:

```
return new FileContentResult(_WordByte, "application/pdf");
```

O código acima não funciona, primeiro eu preciso converter para pdf, alguma solução ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe uma outra opção que é utilizando a biblioteca de interoperabilidade com o Office, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

Testei aqui e consegui fazer assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

static class Program
{
    public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Definição dos endereços dos arquivos de entrada e saida - O endereço deve estar completo
        string docOrigem = "D:\\teste.docx"; 
        string pdfSaida = "D:\\saida.pdf";

        // Utiliza as próprias dll do wor para realizar a conversão
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(docOrigem);
        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfSaida, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);

        // Fecha a aplicação e o documento
        appWord.Quit()
        wordDocument.Close() 
    }
}
```

Depois é só tratar o arquivo PDF gerado como bem entender.
Caso essa solução funcione, aconselho a colocar algumas verificações antes, como por exemplo, testar se o arquivo existe e utilizar `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Guilherme na última linha, você esqueceu de fechar: `wordDocument.Close()` e `appWord.Quit()`. Veja o exemplo da minha resposta :)

Comment: Realmente, fiz na pressa e quando deu certo acabei não revisando o código.
Esse fechamento é muito importante para que os arquivos não fiquem "travados abertos" .

Comment: Como a biblioteca de interoperabilidade com o Office cria objetos COM que são gerenciados pelo Coletor de Lixo do .NET, o processo do Word pode ficar "pendurado" por tempo indeterminado, enquanto a aplicação estiver sendo executada, por isso é importante forçar uma coleção do lixo. Veja essa resposta: [Como salvar um arquivo XLSX (Excel) ao invés de CSV?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347160/86952).

Answer (score 3):

Vou deixar a minha resposta aqui para ajudar o pessoal que ta precisando converter. Na minha lógica estou convertendo (word, excel e powerpoint) para PDF e retorna `bytes[]`:

Antes de ir para a lógica, você precisa instalar 3 componentes, elas são:

***PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word -Version 15.0.4797.1003***

***PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel -Version 15.0.4795.1000***

***PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint -Version 15.0.4420.1017***

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];

string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

byte[] PDF = ConvertToPDF(file, ext);

private byte[] ConvertToPDF(HttpPostedFileBase file, string ext)
{
    //salva o arquivo na pasta App_Data
    string path = Server.MapPath($"~/App_Data/nome_arquivo");
    file.SaveAs($"{path}{ext}");

    //Micrososft Word
    if (ext == ".doc" || ext == ".docx")
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open($"{path}{ext}");
        //Converter para PDF
        doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($"{path}.pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
        doc.Close();
        app.Quit();
        //Leia o arquivo e retorna bytes[]
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{path}.pdf");
    }
    //Microsoft Excel
    if (ext == ".xls" || ext == ".xlsx")
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open($"{path}{ext}");
        //Converter para PDF
        wkb.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, $"{path}.pdf");
        wkb.Close();
        app.Quit();
        //Leia o arquivo e retorna bytes[]
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{path}.pdf");
    }
    //Microsoft PowerPoint
    else
    {
        //ppt || pptx 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = app.Presentations.Open($"{path}{ext}",
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        //Converter para PDF
        presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat($"{path}.pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType.ppFixedFormatTypePDF);
        presentation.Close();
        app.Quit();
        //Leia o arquivo e retorna bytes[]
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"{path}.pdf");
    }
}
```

*Lembrando que no servidor precisa de **Microsoft Office** instalado.*

Comment: Como a biblioteca de interoperabilidade com o Office cria objetos COM que são gerenciados pelo Coletor de Lixo do .NET, o processo do Word pode ficar "pendurado" por tempo indeterminado, enquanto a aplicação estiver sendo executada, por isso é importante forçar uma coleção do lixo. Veja essa resposta: [Como salvar um arquivo XLSX (Excel) ao invés de CSV?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347160/86952).

Answer (score 1):

Como há duas respostas utilizando o **Interop**, resolvi postar uma solução que não faz uso dele, não sendo necessário o Office instalado no servidor.

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o [FreeSpire.DOC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Doc/).

Para instala-lo use o NuGet:

> Install-Package FreeSpire.Doc

Segue abaixo um método de exemplo que recebe o caminho de um arquivo Word e converte para PDF:

#### Se preferir veja o exemplo no GitHub.

```
public static bool ConverterWordParaPDF(string caminhoArquivoWord, string caminhoParaSalvarResultadoPDF, out string nomeArquivoPDF)
{
    nomeArquivoPDF = String.Empty;

    //Se o arquivo não existir, retornar falso
    if (!File.Exists(caminhoArquivoWord))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Gera um guid para usar no nome do arquivo e concatena com o caminho onde o arquivo será armazenado:
    string caminhoCompletoPDF = caminhoParaSalvarResultadoPDF + "\\" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf";

    using (Document document = new Document())
    {
        document.LoadFromFile(caminhoArquivoWord);
        document.SaveToFile(caminhoCompletoPDF, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.PDF);
    }

    if (!File.Exists(caminhoCompletoPDF))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        nomeArquivoPDF = caminhoCompletoPDF;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Exemplo de chamada ao método:**

```
string resultadoPDF;
if(ConverterWordParaPDF(CaminhoArquivoWord, caminhoConversaoPDF, out resultadoPDF))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Arquivo Word convertido com sucesso. Caminho do arquivo: {0}", resultadoPDF));
}
```

*No GitHub há também um exemplo para conversão de arquivos Excel.*

[Leia a documentação do Free Spire.DOC no site do desenvolvedor.](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-doc-component.html)