# Como salvar um arquivo XLSX (Excel) ao invés de CSV?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel, arquivo, csv

Hoje eu tenho o código abaixo, que salva um arquivo em formato CSV.
O que preciso alterar para salvar em formato XLSX (Excel)?

```
public static void buildCSV(string filename = "resultado.xlsx")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Escrevendo no arquivo.");

            StringBuilder csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //cria o header
            csvBuilder.AppendLine("Nome;Cpf;Cep;ID Cliente");

            foreach (var item in BAG)
            {
                csvBuilder.AppendLine(item);
            }

            File.WriteAllText(filename, csvBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Convertendo arquivo word para pdf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316400/convertendo-arquivo-word-para-pdf)

Comment: @MatheusMiranda, não creio que possa ser considerada como duplicata já que o Word e o Excel têm estruturas bem diferentes, o Excel têm worksheets e células, por exemplo, e uma das dúvidas dessa pergunta era sobre como salvar no formato XLSX, enquanto que a dúvida da sua pergunta era sobre como salvar o documento do Word em PDF.

Comment: Tenho a mesma duvida que vc, quando tento executar recebo essa mensagem de erro -> 'O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\resultado.xlsx' foi negado.'
Como faço pra salvar o arquivo em outra pasta que nao seja essa ?

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer isso usando a biblioteca de interoperabilidade do Excel (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`), mas para isso o Excel terá que estar instalado no computador que for executar a sua aplicação.

Para usar esse código é necessário primeiro fazer referência ao namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Uma forma fácil para fazer isso é usando o NuGet. No Visual Studio acesse o menu Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution > Browse, pesquise por *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel* e instale o pacote. Ou faça [assim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41406705/8133067).

O código para criar o arquivo XLSX é esse:

```c#
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

   public static void CriarArquivoXlsx(string filename = "resultado.xlsx")
   {
      _CriarArquivoXlsx(filename);

      // Libera os objetos COM do Excel.
      GC.Collect();
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   }

   private static void _CriarArquivoXlsx(string filename)
   {
      Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
      if (xlApp == null)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Excel não está instalado!");
         return;
      }

      Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
      Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

      // Cabeçalho.
      // A indicação da coluna pode ser por números (1, 2, 3, etc.)
      // ou por texto ("A", "B", "C", etc.).
      int row = 1;
      xlWorksheet.Cells[row, 1] = "Nome";
      xlWorksheet.Cells[row, 2] = "Cpf";
      xlWorksheet.Cells[row, 3] = "Cep";
      xlWorksheet.Cells[row, 4] = "ID Cliente";

      foreach (string item in BAG)
      {
         row++;
         int col = 0;
         foreach (string campo in item.Split(';'))
         {
            col++;
            xlWorksheet.Cells[row, col] = campo;
         }
      }

      xlWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);

      xlWorkbook.Close();
      xlApp.Quit();
   }
```

Eu criei a função privada `_CriarArquivoXlsx()`, que faz o trabalho de verdade, e a função pública `CriarArquivoXlsx()`, que chama a função privada e depois dispara o `GC` (GarbageCollector) para liberar as referências dos objetos COM criados na função privada.

Isso é importante porque, como a biblioteca de interoperabilidade com o Office cria objetos COM, que são gerenciados pelo .NET, e portanto pelo Coletor de Lixo (Garbage Collector) do .NET, o processo do Excel pode ficar "pendurado" por tempo indeterminado enquando a aplicação estiver sendo executada. Por isso é necessário forçar uma coleçao imediata do lixo, liberando assim as referências dos objetos COM do Excel.

O fato de ter colocado a coleção de lixo fora da função que cria os objetos COM é meramente um artifício para que isso funcione corretamente também no modo debug da aplicação, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/8133067) a explicação do porquê se fazer dessa forma.

Referências usadas para a criação do código:

- [I want to create xlsx (Excel) file from c# - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41605649/8133067)
- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet.Cells[x,y].Style? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15926578/8133067)
- [Clean up Excel Interop Objects with IDisposable - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/8133067) (mesmo link citado acima)
- [How to: Access Office Interop Objects by Using Visual C# Features (C# Programming Guide) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects)

---

Também há uma biblioteca open source que permite criar arquivos XLSX sem precisar do Excel instalado, chamada [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). Mais detalhes aqui:

- [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C# - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603625/8133067)