# Exportar gráficos de uma planilha Excel sem Interop

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Eu preciso ler e gravar dados de planilhas Excel, e exportar alguns gráficos, usando C#. Mas eu não posso utilizar a biblioteca de interoperabilidade (`Microsoft.Office.Interop`) para isso.

Como eu posso fazer?
Alguém tem alguma indicação de pacote NuGet para isso?

Conheço o EPPlus, já fiz alguns trabalhos com ele, porém com ele não dá pra exportar gráficos.

Sei que com o EPPlus é possível gravar e ler dados da planilha, e até criar gráficos, mas o problema é no momento de exportar os gráficos, eu preciso exportar esse gráfico já existente em um excel já existente para JPG, PNG ou até em PDF. Mas preferencialmente para JPG.

Comment: Alexandre, aqui as perguntas devem ser feitas em português. Mas, veja o final dessa resposta: [Como salvar um arquivo XLSX (Excel) ao invés de CSV?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347160/86952)

Comment: Ops, achei que ia pro Stack global, desculpe rs.
Então, eu conheço o EPPlus, já fiz alguns trabalhos com ele, porém não da pra manipular gráficos com ele.

Comment: Então traduz a pergunta, por favor, e aproveita e já inclui essa informação, que o EPPlus você já conhece e não serve porque não permite manipular gráficos. Inclusive seria bom você tirar o tag `interop`, já que você quer justamente sem interoperablidade!

Comment: Feito haha, obrigado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Spire.XLS

Fiz uma solução utilizando o componente [Spire.XLS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.XLS/) o [site do desenvolvedor é esse](https://www.e-iceblue.com/) e há uma boa [documentação sobre o componente](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/excel-for-net-introduce.html).

Você pode instalar o [Spire.XLS pelo Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.XLS/):

> Install-Package Spire.XLS -Version 8.11.6

Segue um exemplo de como converti um gráfico de barras do excel para imagem:

```
public void ConvertChartXlsToImg()
{
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.LoadFromFile(@"D:\MinhaPasta\column-chart.xlsx");
    Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
    Image[] imgs = workbook.SaveChartAsImage(sheet);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.Length; i++)
    {
        imgs[i].Save(string.Format("img-{0}.jpeg", i), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

#### Projeto com exemplos no GitHub

Fiz um [**repositório no GitHub**](https://github.com/Wurthma/ExcelChartToImage) com um projeto web que lê um arquivo excel com um gráfico de colunas e converte ele para imagem e imprime na tela.

No exemplo, se você acessar a controler **Home/Index** encontrará como gerar a imagem e salvar em arquivo ou em memória (`byte[]`) e a impressão dela no **View**.

No arquivo excel há apenas um gráfico, mas se outros foram criados todos serão impressos.

**Nota:** O problema é que a versão gratuita desse componente te limita em algumas coisas. Se utilizar apenas para esse fim acredito seu único problema será um texto que é impresso na imagem do gráfico informando que ele foi gerado por esse componente, mas recomendo que leia sobre as limitações no site deles e faça testes com leitura de planilhas maiores e com mais gráfico.

---

## Outros componentes:

### EPPlus

**Com o [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) não encontrei uma forma de renderizar a imagem.** O seguinte código que foi nossa primeira tentativa não funciona apesar de compilar, mas ao tentar ler o gráfico ele não renderiza a imagem e a `var img` vem nula.

Acredito que realmente não é possível, mas deixarei como consulta caso alguém tente utilizar ela.

```
FileInfo arquivoExcel = new FileInfo("CaminhoArquivo");
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(arquivoExcel))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    var img = (ExcelPicture)worksheet.Drawings["Chart 1"];
}
```

---

### Aspose Cells

Outra boa opção é o [Aspose Cells para .NET](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net), mas também não é gratuito e há algumas limitações.

No mesmo projeto do GitHub fiz um método que também imprime a imagem usando o componente Aspose Cells.

Exemplo com Aspose Cells retornando Model com lista de gráficos para impressão:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HomeModel model = new HomeModel();
    model.ListaExcelChartImg = new List<byte[]>();
    //Pegar o caminho do projeto
    string path = Server.MapPath("~");
    //Abrir arquivo excel com Aspose Cells
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook(path + "\\Content\\column-chart.xlsx");
    Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

    foreach (var grafico in worksheet.Charts)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        grafico.ToImage().Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] bmpBytes = ms.ToArray();
        model.ListaExcelChartImg.Add(bmpBytes);

    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Infelizmente não encontrei componente totalmente gratuito que não te limite em algum aspecto que renderiza o gráfico para excel. Mas segue uma [lista de Packages do Nuget que trabalham com arquivo excel](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel?page=1).

Answer (score 2):

Você consegue gerar gráficos utilizando o EPPlus, veja um exemplo:

```
        //Criar o relatório
        var pieChart = (ExcelPieChart)ws.Drawings.AddChart("crtExtensionsSize", eChartType.PieExploded3D);
        pieChart.SetPosition(1, 0, 2, 0);
        pieChart.SetSize(400, 400);
        //Adicionar as séries
        pieChart.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(3, 2, row-1, 2), ExcelRange.GetAddress(3, 1, row-1, 1));
        //Adicionar titulo e configurar o relatório
        pieChart.Title.Text = "Extension Size";
        pieChart.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
        pieChart.DataLabel.ShowPercent = true;
        pieChart.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
        pieChart.Legend.Remove();
```

Você pode ver maiores informações na propria [Wiki do EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Shapes,-Pictures-and-Charts)

Comment: Sim, gerar gráficos eu sei que é possível, porém o que eu preciso é exportar um gráfico existente já no Excel, seja para JPG, PDF, tanto faz o formato ( preferencialmente em JPG ), vou colocar isto na pergunta.
Obrigado